# <jaxrs:client> not getting autowired

Tags: spring, proxy, cxf, autowired

I am trying to build a restful client using jaxrs:client as defined in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/systests/jaxrs/src/test/resources/jaxrs_soap_rest/WEB-INF/beans.xml

In my test class I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.abc.service.ExportServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bankbazaar.service.ExportService com.abc.service.ExportServiceTest.exportClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.abc.service.ExportService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=exportClient)}

this is my spring config

However

```
    exportClient=(ExportService)applicationContext.getBean("exportClient");
```

this works.

Thanks
Himangshu

Comment: CXF uses its own injection mechanism if you dont define <context:annotation-config/> in your application context. 
If you have done this already please provide the applicationContext.xml. Otherwise it can be hard to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The fully qualified classname for the two ExportService looks different `com.abc.service.ExportService` vs `com.bankbazaar.service.ExportService`. Fixing the two to point to the same name should fix the problem. Check the package name of the ExportService defined via applicationContext.getBean()  to acertain the difference.